# How to deploy Envoy EDS/SDS

Tags: microservices, envoyproxy

This is a micro services deployment question. How would you deploy [Envoy SDS](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/service_discovery#service-discovery-service-sds)(service discovery service) so other envoy proxies can find the SDS server hosts, in order to discover other services to build the service mesh. Should I put it behind a load balancer with a DNS name( single point of failure) or just run the SDS locally in every machine so other micro services can access it? Or is there a better way of deployment that SDS cluster can be dynamically added into envoy config without a single point of failure?

Comment: This seems to be a nice question for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @MatheusSantana I posted it at https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/how-to-deploy-envoy-eds-sds, since its more appropriate there.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it behind a DNS name with a load balancer across multiple SDS servers is a good setup for reasonable availability. If SDS is down, Envoy will simple not get updated, so it's generally not the most critical failure -- new hosts and services simply won't get added to the cluster/endpoint model in Envoy.

If you want higher availability, you set up multiple clusters. If you add multiple entries to your bootstrap config, Envoy will fail over between them. You can either specify multiple DNS names or multiple IPs.

**(My answer after misunderstanding the question below, for posterity)**

> You can start with a static config or DNS, but you'll probably want to
>   check out a full integration with your service discovery.
>
> Check out [Service Discovery
>   Integration](https://www.learnenvoy.io/articles/service-discovery.html)
>   on LearnEnvoy.io.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link, its pretty good. But I guess you confused my question, it was about how to find xDS service hosts in the network. Not about integrating with xDS.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Updating my answer. Putting it behind DNS + a load balancer is great.